# Rest Services and CSRF

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

I have a number of services accessed by singe page apps. I want to enable CSRF across those apps, but if they each have their own CSRF Token Repository then i have an issue of different tokens for different apps, even though they share the same session.

Is there a shared CSRF Token Store implementation whereby services share a common token generation/validation mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Security, the CSRF Token is stored in the session by default (see `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository`). Therefore if your apps are sharing the same session, they should be configured to share the CSRF Token as well.